# How to download with wget without following links with parameters

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I'm trying to download two sites for inclusion on a CD:

```
http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki
http://www.boinc-wiki.info
```

The problem I'm having is that these are both wikis. So when downloading with e.g.:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif http://www.boinc-wiki.info/
```

I do get a **lot of files** because it also follows links like ...?action=edit ...?action=diff&version=...

Does somebody know a way to get around this?

I just want the current pages, without images, and without diffs etc.

P.S.:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -l 1 -R jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,pdf,ppt http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/TitleIndex
```

This worked for berkeley but boinc-wiki.info is still giving me trouble :/

P.P.S:

I got what appears to be the most relevant pages with:

```
wget -r -k -nv  -l 2 -R jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,pdf,ppt http://www.boinc-wiki.info
```

Comment: No need to cross post between superuser and serverfault http://superuser.com/questions/158318/how-to-download-with-wget-without-following-links-with-parameters

Comment: Where should I have posted it?

Answer (score 8):

```
wget --reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)' http://example.com
```

(`--reject-type posix` by default).  Works only for recent (>=1.14) versions of `wget` though, according to other comments.

Beware that it seems you can use `--reject-regex` only once per `wget` call.  That is, you have to use `|` in a single regex if you want to select on several regex :

```
wget --reject-regex 'expr1|expr2|…' http://example.com
```

Comment: Regex in wget are not anchored at beginning or end, so in your first example `wget --reject-regex '\?' http://example.com` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

The  [documentation for wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html) says:

> Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (‘?’) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings.

It looks like this functionality [has been on the table for awhile](http://www.mail-archive.com/wget%40sunsite.dk/msg08816.html) and nothing has been done with it.

I haven't used it, but [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) looks like it has a more robust filtering feature set than wget and may be a better fit for what you're looking for (read about filters here http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html).

Comment: +1 for pointing me to httrack. It looks better then wget, and wget is looking stagnant.

Comment: I've tried Winhttrack but it behaves funny. It downloads files and traverses directories it should not :/

Comment: Maybe one day wget will be fixed.  For now httrack and pavuk both look good.

Answer (score 3):

The new version of ***wget (v.1.14)*** solves all these problems.

You have to use the new option `--reject-regex=....` to handle query strings.

Note that I couldn't find the new manual that includes these new options, so you have to use the help command `wget --help > help.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Pavuk should be able to do it:

http://pavuk.sourceforge.net/man.html#sect39

Mediawiki example:

> [...]
>
> -skip_url_pattern ’*oldid=*, *action=edit*, *action=history*, *diff=*, *limit=*,
>   *[/=]User:*, *[/=]User_talk:*, *[^p]/Special:*, *=Special:[^R]*, *.php/Special:[^LUA][^onl][^nul]*,
>   *MediaWiki:*, *Search:*, *Help:*’
>
> [...]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to avoid download special pages of MediaWiki. I solved this problem once avoiding the `index.php` page:

```
wget  -R '*index.php*'  -r ... <wiki link>
```

However, the wiki used the URLS as seen in Wikipedia (`http://<wiki>/en/Theme`) and not the pattern I have seen in other places (`http://<wiki>/index.php?title=Theme`). Since [the link you gave](http://www.boinc-wiki.info/) uses URLs in the Wikipedia pattern, I think this solution can work for you too, though.

Answer (score 0):

‘-R rejlist --reject rejlist’
Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

Patterns are probably what you want.
I am not sure how sophisticated the patterns are but you can either try to accept only certain files or block:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif,*\? http://www.boinc-wiki.info/
```

Accept:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif -A [a-zA-Z.] http://www.boinc-wiki.info/
```

**Edit: nvm in light of the other post.**

Comment: This works on query strings? Every version of wget I've used only applies reject list patterns to the file portion of the URL. I'll give it a shot and see.

Comment: I haven't tested it. I just looked up the documentation. I did find it uses shell convention, but your experience would speak more than mine in regard to the working function of the matching.

Comment: Escaping the "?" doesn't seem to get wget to do what the OP would like on my CentOS 5.3 box running wget 1.11.4.